# how to handle empty line in logging request headers in flask

Tags: python, logging, flask

I just want log request.headers in logfile, but when I logging it:

```
logging.debug("Headers:{0}".format(request.headers))
```

there are so many empty lines in log, how to cut them?

I find it has '/r/n' between lines, but when I use split('\r\n'), not work well.
Any sugguestion?

Comment: `request.headers` is a dictionary

Comment: So you can perhaps use `logging.debug('Headers:{0}'.format(json.dumps(request))`

Answer (score 0):

```
headers = "\n".join(filter(lambda x : x!="" ,[line.strip() for line in str(request.headers).split("\n")] ))
```

My colleague helped me.